# How to create a shared library for Android from Windows QtCreator

Tags: android, c++, qt, cmake, qml

**What I have**

---

Project on C++ - MyLibC build system CMake 3.14

> CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(MyLibC LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_library(MyLibC SHARED
  MyLibC.cpp
  MyLibC.h
)

target_compile_definitions(MyLibC PRIVATE MYLIBC_LIBRARY)
```

.cpp and .h files have empty class.

Project on QtQuick - MyProjQt build system qmake

> myprojqt.pro

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++14

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        testclass.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/lib" -libmylibc

unix {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS=$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/lib/libmylibc.so
}

win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += "$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/include"
    LIBS += "$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/lib/libmylibc.dll"
}

TRANSLATIONS += \
    myprojqt_en_US.ts

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    testclass.h
```

**What I alredy did**

1. Added toolchain.cmake file in lib project toolchain.cmake

> toolchain.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
```

2. Added flag to start CMake parametrs -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./toolchain.cmake ..
3. Builded lib and recived libmylibc.so
4. Added .so and .h to MyProjQt
5. Builded MyProjQt and have a problem.

> Errors

```
:-1: ошибка: error: /lib/libmylibc.so:1:3: invalid character
:-1: ошибка: error: /lib/libmylibc.so:1:3: syntax error, unexpected $end
:-1: ошибка: error: /lib/libmylibc.so: not an object or archive
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Qt 5.15.2
CMake 3.14.2
MinGW 8.1.0 64-bit for C++
Android Clang (C++, arm, NDK 21.3.6528147)

p.s. 
I already did it once, but I forgot how

Answer (score 0):

In a `qmake` project you will only need

```
TEMPLATE = lib
```

And it does the work to build the shared lib. Please be aware that if you ever want to use anything that needs a Qt event loop, you must instantiate and exec a QCoreApplication when loading your shared library.

Comment: I'm building a library using CMake with an toolchain and there I specify the target platform

Comment: @ИванБогданов how do you handle multiabi build for Android in CMake? this is not related to your original question. Just to know

Comment: I'm using qmake for Android app, and CMake for crossplatform build library by Android and Windows from Windows